# Sir John Eccles and Professor John Searle debate

Tags: reference-request

While lecturing about [DesCartes' thoughts regarding](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pineal-gland/) the [pineal gland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pineal_gland) (where the "soul" is attached to the body) Professor Searle mentions a [similar line of thinking](http://www.neuroquantology.com/index.php/journal/article/viewFile/8/8) in the work of neurophysiologist and philosopher [Sir John "Jack" Eccles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Eccles_(neurophysiologist)). In the lecture, [Searle goes on to say](https://youtu.be/c14ZI80-gPo?t=32m56s) that he and Eccles debated each other and that the debate was televised in Britain. Does anyone know of the program ("Voices"?), the existence of a copy or a transcript? So far the following is all I have discovered in [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_atheist_philosophers#cite_ref-125) to the debate:

> Reviewing an episode of the Channel 4 series Voices: "On the one hand, Sir John Eccles, a quiet-spoken theist with the most devastating way of answering questions with a single "yes", on the other, Professor Searle, a flamboyant atheist using words I've never heard of or likely to again "now we know that renal secretions synthesize a substance called angiotensin and that angiotensin gets into the hypothalamus and causes a series of neuron firings". " Peter Dear, 'Today's television and radio programmes', The Times, February 22, 1984; pg. 31; Issue 61764; col A.

I'm nowhere near UC Berkeley's Moffit Library Media Center, but I understand they have [a copy](http://ist-socrates.berkeley.edu/~jsearle/132/) there...?